# Automating email reply for specific message

Tags: ruby, winapi, vbscript, wsh, win32ole

Is there a way to automate reply to a particular message. The process here is that you make a request through, eg. outlook, and then reply to the response of the request you made.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you make your application periodically check for mail in the inbox using POP3 or IMAP and do something if there's a message that matches with the format of your request.

Something like (not actually a working example, more like pseudo code)

```
mail=Mail.login(:server => 'foo', 
                :user => 'john', 
                :password => 'john_is_the_king_pimp'
)
while 1==1
  mail.new_messages do |msg|
    if msg.subject.match(/^REQUEST/) 
      read stuff from the message and do something about it
    end
  end
  sleep 60
end
```

Comment: Nice idea. What if the system do not need a subject at first? And then the system create one.

Comment: Just go through all emails then and look for the request in the message body if you need one.